# trouble reading structure from stream, or bytes rather

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a LAS File 1.3 Header from a file.

In every single header that I've seen, The first thing i expect to read is the Format Signature which is always "LASF".

When i try and read the file, All I'm seeing is 'ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ'

I know the header size is 227, I tried to even just read a length of 227 straight from the file but i still don't read what I'm supposed to. I hope this makes sense.

this is what i've tried:

```
typedef struct Header
{
    char File_Signature[4]; 
    USHORT SourceID;
    USHORT Reserved1;
    UINT GUID1;
    USHORT GUID2;
    USHORT GUID3;    
    char GUID4[8];        
    BYTE VersionMajor;        
    BYTE VersionMinor;
    char SystemID[32];        
    char GeneratingSoftware[32];        
    USHORT DOY;        
    USHORT YEAR;        
    USHORT HeaderSize;    
    UINT PointOffset;    

    INT NumberOfVariableLengthRecords;    
    BYTE PointDataFormatID;    
    USHORT PointDataRecordLength;    
    INT NumberOfPointRecords;    
    UINT NumberofPointsByReturn1;    
    UINT NumberofPointsByReturn2;    
    UINT NumberofPointsByReturn3;    
    UINT NumberofPointsByReturn4;    
    UINT NumberofPointsByReturn5;

    double XScaleFactor;    
    double YScaleFactor;    
    double ZScaleFactor;    
    double Xoffset;    
    double Yoffset;    
    double Zoffset;    
    double MaxX;    
    double MinX;    
    double MaxY;        
    double MinY;        
    double MaxZ;        
    double MinZ;
} LasHeader;




void OpenLasFile()
{

    //THIS DOES NOT WORK
    char buffer[227];
    ifstream myFile ("C:\atlass\area_cov.las");
    myFile.read (buffer, 227);


    //NOT WORK, TRIED THIS TOO
    ifstream input_file("C:\atlass\area_cov.las", ios::binary);
    LasHeader header;

    input_file.read((char*)&header, sizeof(header));   
    input_file.close();


    //ALL DATA OUTPUT'ed ARE 'ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ'
}
```

This is a block of binary from the file I'm trying to read.

```
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
```

My question is: Why am i Reading garbage values, what have i done wrong?

-------------------- UPDATE --------------------------

I tested this and it worked, So it must be a problem reading the file, can anyone help?

what worked was:

```
unsigned char rawData[552] =
{
    0x4C, 0x41, 0x53, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 
    0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x01, 0x02, 0x41, 0x74, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 
    0x20, 0x41, 0x74, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x41, 0x74, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x73, 0x43, 
    0x6F, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 
    0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x1E, 0x01, 0xDC, 0x07, 0xE3, 0x00, 
    0xE3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x1C, 0x00, 0x14, 0x01, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x14, 
    0x01, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFC, 0xA9, 0xF1, 0xD2, 0x4D, 0x62, 0x50, 0x3F, 0xFC, 0xA9, 0xF1, 0xD2, 0x4D, 
    0x62, 0x50, 0x3F, 0xFC, 0xA9, 0xF1, 0xD2, 0x4D, 0x62, 0x50, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB0, 
    0x53, 0x20, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0xFF, 0x53, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE7, 0xB3, 0xFA, 0x83, 0x88, 0xA9, 0x20, 0x41, 0x1B, 0x56, 0x11, 0xE9, 0xBC, 
    0x1B, 0x20, 0x41, 0x77, 0x10, 0xD2, 0x7C, 0x27, 0x11, 0x54, 0x41, 0x14, 0xA5, 0xEC, 0x80, 0x7E, 
    0xF4, 0x53, 0x41, 0xC5, 0x20, 0xB0, 0x72, 0x68, 0x5D, 0x68, 0x40, 0x37, 0x89, 0x41, 0x60, 0xE5, 
    0xD0, 0x12, 0xC0, 0x21, 0xBE, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x06, 0x66, 0x17, 0x01, 0xA9, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD8, 
    0x03, 0xC9, 0x02, 0xE2, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xAC, 0x71, 0x36, 0xBD, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x37, 
    0xB9, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x77, 0x58, 0x17, 0x01, 0xD7, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE2, 0x0A, 0xC9, 0x02, 0xE2, 
    0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x4B, 0x90, 0x11, 0x90, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x00, 0xBF, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x98, 
    0x3A, 0x17, 0x01, 0x2B, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0x23, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xBF, 
    0xF5, 0x61, 0xBD, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x1A, 0xBD, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x30, 0x11, 0x17, 0x01, 0xE4, 
    0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDF, 0x08, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xF8, 0x6E, 0xF3, 0xA6, 0xE3, 
    0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x01, 0xBE, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x16, 0x01, 0x83, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCB, 
    0x06, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE5, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0B, 0xF3, 0x1E, 0xA7, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0xF2, 
    0xBB, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x99, 0xD9, 0x16, 0x01, 0x6D, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x09, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE5, 
    0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x82, 0x1C, 0x94, 0x90, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0xFA, 0xBE, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x98, 
    0xBE, 0x16, 0x01, 0x13, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x08, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE5, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xE5, 
    0xF0, 0x49, 0xA7, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0xEE, 0xBC, 0x92, 0xFF, 0xDE, 0xB0, 0x16, 0x01, 0x04, 
    0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8E, 0x0B, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE5, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x95, 0xA0, 0xBF, 0x90, 0xE3, 
    0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0xD2, 0xBD, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x19, 0x88, 0x16, 0x01, 0xA9, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD1, 
    0x08, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE7, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA7, 0x24, 0xEB, 0x90, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0xA8, 
    0xBE, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x29, 0x64, 0x16, 0x01, 0x97, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFD, 0x04, 0x49, 0x02, 0xE7, 
    0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC4, 0xF0, 0x11, 0x91, 0xE3, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x79, 0xD0, 0x92, 0xFF, 0xD0, 
    0x70, 0x17, 0x01, 0x30, 0x61, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x02, 0xC9, 0x02, 0xE2, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x91, 
    0x65, 0xC1, 0x44, 0xE4, 0x25, 0x04, 0x41, 0x12, 0xC7, 0x92, 0xFF, 0x02, 0x5E, 0x17, 0x01, 0x79, 
    0x61, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79, 0x05, 0xC9, 0x02, 0xE2, 
} ;


LasHeader test;

memcpy(&test, rawData, sizeof(test));
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and it appears not to be open, Why would that be?

I tried this:

 myFile.open("C:\atlass\area_cov.las");

 if (myFile.is_open())
 {
  myFile.read (buffer, 227);
 }

Comment: I think you should add `ios::in`: `ifstream input_file("C:\atlass\area_cov.las",  ios::in | ios::binary);`

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes.  `"c:\\atlass\\area_cov.las"`

Comment: If you plan to read a struct/class from a file, you might want to check whether the compiler is adding padding bytes between any struct/class member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
    ifstream myFile ("C:\atlass\area_cov.las");
```

Backslash is a special character in C strings that forms [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). In this particular case, `\a` is replaced by a [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) (`0x0B`), so it is trying to open the wrong path and failing.

Instead, you need to escape all the backslashes that occur in the path by doubling them:

```
    ifstream myFile ("C:\\atlass\\area_cov.las");
```